# How can I extract multiple 7z files in folder at once in Ubuntu?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, extract, 7zip

How can I extract about 900 7z files which are all located in the same folder (all have only one file inside) without doing it one by one?

I am using Ubuntu 10.10. All files are located in `/home/username/folder1/folder2`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
for arc in *.7z
do
  7zwhatever "$arc"
done
```

Answer (score 50):

```
7za -y x "*.7z"
```

The above code worked for me

Comment: Quotes were the needed component I was missing. It didn't want to work without them.

Comment: On Fedora 38 I had to comment out the asterisk, `\*.7z`

Answer (score 11):

Using [parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) is rather convenient way with total progress meter for free ;)

```
ls *.7z | parallel -j+0 --eta '7z x {} >/dev/null'
```

Answer (score 10):

`7z x "*.7z"`
this worked for me in ubuntu

Comment: Maybe you explain a little bit more what this line does, for example by citing the manpage. This may help other users with the same issue to better understand **how** this solves the problem.

Comment: Practically the same as [the current top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39369247/6404709) (posted in 2016), only doesn't have the `-y` flag (confirm all). Has Ubuntu had a package supplying the `7z` command?

Answer (score 7):

```
for f in *.7z
do
    7zr e "$f" &
done
```

This will extract all `.7z` files if they're 7z format to the current directory, without waiting for completion.

Your computer could be owned. You have been warned!

Comment: If you have 900 files then yeah, that will be pain.

Answer (score 6):

If you wish to extract multiple 7zip archives to folders with the same names in Linux, you can use:

```
for archive in *.7z; do 7z x -o"`basename \"$archive\" .7z`" "$archive"; done
```

For example, if you have two 7zip archives `a.7z` and `b.7z`, it will create two folders `a` and `b`, and uncompress `a.7z` into folder `a` and  `b.7z` into folder `b`.

The above command comes from [this answer on superuser](https://superuser.com/a/999623/116475) by user [Vojtech](https://superuser.com/users/518980/vojtech).

Answer (score 5):

You do not need to overcomplicate things. To extract a 7-Zip archive split to multiply parts use the following command:

```
7z x archive.7zip.0
```

7-Zip will notice you that you have a multi-volume archive and it unpacks everything.

Comment: this worked great. also I used `7z x archive.7zip.00*` and it put back together the two .001 and .002 files.

Answer (score 5):

Probably the simplest approach is below

```
 ls | xargs -n1 7z x
```

Answer (score 0):

in adition to using a for loop

you can also use find in combination with the exec argument or xargs

Answer (score 0):

Another example with -aos parameter.

```
# ls Environment-voice-20180629-20180705-20230706024500.zip Environment-voice-20180729-20180802-20230706050000.zip | xargs -n1 7za x -aos '-xr!/http*'

7-Zip (a) [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
p7zip Version 16.02 (locale=C.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,16 CPUs Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8272CL CPU @ 2.60GHz (50657),ASM,AES-NI)

Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 2928050140 bytes (2793 MiB)

Extracting archive: Environment-voice-20180629-20180705-20230706024500.zip
--
Path = Environment-voice-20180629-20180705-20230706024500.zip
Type = zip
Physical Size = 2928050140
64-bit = +

Everything is Ok

Files: 631108
Size:       2664870996
Compressed: 2928050140

7-Zip (a) [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
p7zip Version 16.02 (locale=C.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,16 CPUs Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8272CL CPU @ 2.60GHz (50657),ASM,AES-NI)

Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 2387436055 bytes (2277 MiB)

Extracting archive: Environment-voice-20180729-20180802-20230706050000.zip
--
Path = Environment-voice-20180729-20180802-20230706050000.zip
Type = zip
Physical Size = 2387436055
64-bit = +

Everything is Ok

Files: 505001
Size:       2177832150
Compressed: 2387436055
```

Answer (score -2):

The simplest way is `unzip '*.zip'`.

Make sure you have the `'` marks.